# VBA FormulaR1C1wrong column from column AA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-r1c1-notation

I am using the below code to add a formula to a cell:

```
Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = 
"=RC" & Range("Col2").Column & 
"-RC" & Range("Col28").Column & 
"-RC" & Range("Col54").Column
```

What I'm expecting in Cell A1:

```
=B1-AB1-BB1
```

What happens is:

```
=B1-AC1-BD1
```

From column AA it is shifted by one column and from column BA by two columns.

In which area (A to Z or AA to AZ or BA to BZ) the linked cells are located is only known at runtime. Therefore it does NOT work:

```
Cells(1,1).FormulaR1C1 = 
"=RC" & Range("Col2").Column & 
"-RC" & Range("Col28").Column -1 &
"-RC" & Range("Col54").Column -2
```

Comment: double check that you are passing the correct column number. Maybe your named range is not pointing at what you think it is.

Comment: oh and btw, Column AP is column 42 not 41.

Comment: thanks, 've simplified it now.

Comment: I assume those are named ranges.  Can we see how they are defined?

Comment: ^^^ if they are not names ranges, you may be looking for `Columns(2).Column` though at that point you may as well just use `2`, `28` and `54`

Comment: What's the output from `Debug.Print Range("Col2").Column, Range("Col28").Column, Range("Col54").Column` ?

Comment: Yes, the cells are named because the location of the cell always changes depending on how many entries precede the cell in the same row. The Debug Print says 2, 28 and 54. But the cell then suddenly contains the incorrect formula.